# MVC email template engine .netcoreapp1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, email-templates, mailkit

I'm new with ASP.NET Core and I am trying to make emails, based on templates.
I want to include tags, which are then replaced with specific data from the controller.

I found a engine called razorengine that was exectly what I was looking for, but it is not compatible with .netcoreapp1.1. Are there other alternatives that I could use?

I am using Mailkit btw.

UPDATE:

I found a alternative called [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/), Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) which allows the same using the built-in Razor engine and runs with .Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include an extra library for that.

Just create an html file that lies in your project scope and mark your placeholders e.g. via `{{ ... }}`

For example create a file `wwwroot/emails/welcome.html`:

```
Dear {{user}},

<p>Have fun with this page.</p>
<p>Please click <a href="{{link}}">here</a> to activate your account.</p>

Best wishes
```

Now in your controller action:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SendSomeEmailTo(userId)
{
  string body;
  using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenText("wwwroot/emails/welcome.html"))  
  {
    body = file.ReadToEnd();
  }

  var user = this.userManager.findById(userId);
  // replace your placeholders here
  body = body
    .Replace("{{user}}", user.getFullName())
    .Replace("{{link}}", "www.foo.bar");

  // use the email body in your email service of your choice
  await sender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "Welcome", body);
}
```